# Assign value PHP variable as column name during fetching

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to fetch the values from columns in a MySQL table using PHP. The variable `$batch_id` is dynamic, i.e. it changes column name depending on the request. Say, it can adopt value like 'Batch1' or 'Batch10'. I was able to extract the column name into the `$batch_id` variable, but when I am passing the column name, say 'Batch10' the array `$batch_Value` is populated with 'Batch10' rather than the values of that column. I am sure there must be a simple solution, but I am stuck. Any help will be appreciated. I am using the following code.

```
$batch_Value = array();
if($num>0){
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row);
        $batch_Value[] = $batch_id;
    }
}
```

[image]

On the left what I am getting and on the right is the expected outcome. But right hand one I am getting when I am using the Column name directly

Comment: `$batch_Value[] = $row[$batch_id];`

Comment: Show 2 examples of what you get in `$row` and what you want the result to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch the data as number-indexed array instead of associative one. Also, don't use extract, it's unsafe because it can overwrite existing variables.

```
$batch_Value = array();
if($num>0){
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
      $batch_Value[] = $row[0];
    }
}
```

Or if the desired column is not the first one, then you can find the value in the `$row` array (which is an associative one, see `print_r($row);` for details about it), with the following:

```
$batch_Value = array();
if($num>0){
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $batch_Value[] = $row[$batch_id];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never use `extract` in your code. This will lead to a number of problems.

PDO has a lot of useful fetch modes. I don't see any reason to use `while` loop.

You can fetch values from a single column like this:

```
$batch_Value = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

This will give you a 1D array with a list of the values from the first column.

If you want to fetch full row, indexed by the first column, then you can use `PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE`:

```
$batch_Value = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
```

For the description of all fetch modes see https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes

Comment: You can also fetch an other column using `$batch_Value = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE, index);` where the index is a 0 based column index.